# Keep Notepad++ from automatically populating the search value with selected/adjacent text

Tags: replace, settings, notepad++

In Notepad++, when you do Search -> Find, it automatically populates the "Find what:" field according to the behavior below (per the online documentation - emphasis mine)...

> In the Find what field, type the text you want to find. ***This is
>   automatically filled with the current selected text, or the word under
>   the caret, or the last searched pattern,*** when the Find dialog is
>   opened.

Is there a way to change or disable this behavior?  I would prefer that it come up empty.  I don't mind the last searched pattern as a reasonable default, but it drives me nuts when it keeps changing the search value by automatically selecting a word next to the cursor.

I've done quite a bit of digging (settings, help, web searches, etc.) and can't find a way to turn this off.

Comment: There is a feature request to make this optional: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3243

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has been fixed since 2019. I downloaded version 7.8.8 and found an option to turn this feature off in Settings > Preferences > MISC > Don't fill find field in Find dialog with selected word.

Comment: Thank you! It has indeed... https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/7a1096de5b3618bc3e6611e6c25caac952d41ae2 and https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3243

Comment: If some keyboard shortcuts no longer work after upgrading to a newer version, just look in Settings>Shortcut Mapper.

Comment: It seems this option has moved - it's now in Settings > Preferences > Searching

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard option to do this but you can achieve it by:

1. The harder way: download N++ sources and make your own N++ build with desired modification
2. The easier way: using [AutoHotKey](http://www.ahkscript.org/) tool, capture <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> shortcut (with condition only if N++ window is active, see `#IfWinActive` directive ) so when it is pressed, send keys <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Similar for <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> (Replace)

The AHK macros which work for me are:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

;--------------------------------- Hotkeys for Notepad++ only
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad\+\+

; present 'find' dialog with empty field
^f::Send ^f{Backspace}  

; present 'replace' dialog with empty field
^h::Send ^h{Backspace}  

; another example: close document with either ^F4 or ^W
^F4::Send ^w

#IfWinActive
```

For details regarding AutoHotkey macro setup, please check [steps 1-5 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/notepad-automatically-change-tab-size/22880354#22880354).

Comment: That's too bad. I love notepad++ to death but this "feature" really slows me down..

Comment: The problem here is that when N++ selects the text, it moves the internal pointer to the end of the selected text, which means that anything you search for won't included the previously-selected text. It makes it harder to deal with regular expression searches. That's why a simple backspace won't work... the pointer is already moved regardless of what's in the find dialog.