# In notepad++ change tab size instantly

Tags: macros, notepad++, tab-size

I'm using notepad++ (v6.5.3) and I constantly have to change the size of the tab for viewing some results. Not that it's taking me a lot of time to do it manually everytime, but it would be great if I could optimize that.
Is there a way to do so? Would a macro be the solution, or are they just for typing stuff?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you changing that tab size? I'm using `Preferences -> TabSettings -> TabSize` and the value is kept set correctly even if I restart N++.

Comment: That's what I am doing as well, and I was just wondering if there was a possible way of doing it faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, there's an easy way how you can achieve this - I have tested it right now:

1. Install [AutoHotKey](http://www.ahkscript.org/) (or start portable version which runs without installation)
2. In Windows 7 and above, ensure you launched AutoHotKey **as Administrator** (otherwise you get inconsistencies in its behavior) - if not sure, exit it and restart it as administrator
3. Right click Autohotkey tray icon and select `Edit This Script`
4. Import the macro below this list at the end of the AutoHotKey script file and save the file
5. Right click Autohotkey tray icon and select `Reload This Script`.
   –– **This was end of general steps, now let's go with your macro:** ––
6. In N++, display `Preferences` window and press its **Close** button<sup>1</sup> at the bottom (NOT at the top-right corner)
7. Now you can use shortcuts <kbd>Win+F2</kbd> and <kbd>Win+F3</kbd> to switch different tab sizes instantly

```
    SendMode Input
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

    ;--------------------------------- Hotkeys for Notepad++ only
    #IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad\+\+

    #F2::Send {F10}{Right 6}{Down}{Enter}{Tab 2}{Space}16{Enter}{Tab 3}{Space}
    #F3::Send {F10}{Right 6}{Down}{Enter}{Tab 2}{Space}4{Enter}{Tab 3}{Space}

    #IfWinActive
```

<sup>1</sup>) **Important:** N++ user experience provided in dialog boxes is absolutely *terrible*. There are no anchors where you can fix focus when using keyboard. Thus **you always need to perform `step 4` *manually* when leaving `Preferences` dialog box** otherwise the macros would send keys into incorect window page OR at correct page but incorrect control. `Preferences` dialog window remembers selected page and control. Macros I created for you therefore assume that correct page is already listed and button **Close** was recently focused.
Good news is Notepad++ windows with this weird behavior are rare exception from general user experience. In other places in N++ (or in other apps) where user interface components (menus, dialogs etc.) **always start from the same point** you do not need any special precautions like the one in **step 4**.

Adjust the macros as you like:

- you can create more of them
- you can adjust the numbers "16" and "4" typed into tab size input box
- you can change shortcut keys to something else
- you can replace sending keys with sending mouse clicks at desired screen/window positions
- you can achieve many other useful shortcuts in N++ and in all other apps – check AHK deeper!